# Cut - Paste an auto-detected range in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to cut and paste chunks of cells, with auto-detected line range, in a defined position (specifically, right after last used cell in column A or B).

```
Sub Cut_Range_To_Clipboard()

'Detecting number of used lines in the chunck of code I need to cut
Dim LastRow As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "T").End(xlUp).Row
        MsgBox LastRow
    End With

'Detecting number of used lines in the column I need to paste the code  
Dim LastRow2 As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        MsgBox LastRow2
    End With

'Cells(20, 3) = T3

Range(Cells(20, 3), Cells(36, LastRow)).Cut
Range(Cells(2, LastRow2 + 1)).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Range("T1").Cut
Range(Cells(1, LastRow2 + 1)).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Columns("T:AK").EntireColumn.Delete
End Sub
```

When executing the code, the line `Range(Cells(2, LastRow2 + 1)).Select` outputs error 1004, and I cannot understand why.

Comment: Just use `Cells(2, LastRow2 + 1)` without the range.  Range

Comment: `Cells([row], [column])`... are you sure about `Cells(2, LastRow2 + 1)`??? away from syntax-errors, you may flipped over row and column here ;)

Comment: @DirkReichel you were right. Thank you!

Comment: @ScottCraner and you were right as well. Is working just with Cells.

Comment: I suggest the last row simply was bigger than the count of columns...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `Address` property of the `Cells` (Necessary whenever you call a Range with only one Cell argument).  So:

```
Range(Cells(2, LastRow2 + 1).Address).Select
```

While this will fix your problem, there are many changes you should look to make in your code, including avoiding select, which will improve performance and avoid other issues

Answer (score 1):

Change your line:

```
Range(Cells(2, LastRow2 + 1)).Select
```

To:

```
Range("B" & LastRow2 + 1).Select
```